# Are inline if statements efficient when used in this way?

Tags: c#

If I assign a value to a variable and then want to assign a second value to it, but only if it fulfills a condition, is it just as efficient to use a shorthand if statement? Here is an example.

Is this more efficient

```
int x = GetInt();
if (x < 5)
    x = 5;
```

Than this

```
int x = GetInt();
x = x < 5 ? 5 : x;
```

I suppose that what I'm really asking is if `x` does not satisfy the condition then will the `x = x` in the else statement impact the performance?

Comment: I can't see that having any serious impact on performance, but the above code is easier to read / see what's going on at a glance

Comment: I guess that `if(x < 5) x = 5;` is more readable than `x = x < 5 ? 5 : x;` and is one line only also. so why use the second one?

Comment: if x isn't associated with getters/setters, the compiler should kick out any statement in the form of `x = x`.

Comment: Yes it is a bit easier on the eyes, I'm thinking specifically about the .NET micro framework where every drop of performance matters.

Comment: How 'bout: `int x = Math.Max(5, GetInt());`. Otherwise, this is premature optimization. What's faster today might be slower tomorrow with a simple framework update that uses a new jit optimization.

Comment: I think it's more of a Min thing

Comment: @MikeyMouse No, he needs Max() here. If GetInt() returns, say, 1, he needs it to pick the larger number.

Comment: Sebastion - Ah, so that else statement should never actually make it in to IL? Post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as best answer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Ah, of course. For some reason I assumed Max would return the bigger of the two numbers

Comment: @JoeNFU If the compiler manages to remove the redundant `x = x` assignment, it wouldn't even matter what framework this code is running on. Besides, most of the time you won't notice the effect of these micro-optimizations except for truly intensive tasks.

Comment: @MikeyMouse Max() does return the bigger number, but that's what he needs here.

Comment: The compiler optimizer will likely be efficient enough to make those two versions equivalent in performance. At least in the simple example provided.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah, I'm confusing myself now. Not sure what I was thinking

Comment: Ugh. Please use braces...so many stupid little bugs as a result of somebody tacking on another line to what-they-thought-was-still-inside-the-if-scope...annoying, perhaps, but far less so that digging for missing braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If x isn't associated with getters/setters, the compiler should kick out any statement in the form of x = x. And consequently any else would be gone, too.

Answer (score 11):

I like this version:

```
int x = Math.Max(5, GetInt());
```

But keep in mind that all of these are premature optimizations. What's faster today may be slower tomorrow with something as simple as a Windows Update that changes the framework to add a new or different JIT optimization.

Where I might spend some time looking is if you're running a check like this inside a large loop:

```
 var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000);

 foreach(int item in items)
 {
     if (item % 3 == 0)
     { 
         //...
     }
     else
     {
         //...
     }
 }
```

The reason for checking the loop is not as much because the code will be run many many times as quickly as possible, putting more emphasis on small inefficiencies, but because whether you use the `if` or the `else` changes back and forth throughout the loop.

I'd expect that code to be inefficient, because of a feature of modern cpu's known as **branch prediction**. If the contents of the `if` and `else` are significant enough and sufficiently different, you can make that code run a *lot* faster by moving doing all of those checks (and putting all the prediction fails) at the front end, and then running all the `if`s together followed by all the `else`s. It will be faster because the branch prediction during the second phase that runs the if's and else's (which is presumably much more expensive to run) will be more accurate.

Here's a little program to demonstrate the difference:

```
class Program
{
    static int samplesize = 1000000;
    //ensure these are big enough that we don't spend time allocating new buffers while the stopwatch is running
    static Dictionary<int, string> ints = new Dictionary<int,string>(samplesize * 4); 
    static Dictionary<double,string> doubles = new Dictionary<double,string>(samplesize * 4);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = Enumerable.Range(0, samplesize).ToArray() ;
        var clock = new Stopwatch();

        test1(items); //jit hit, discard first run. Also ensure all keys already exist in the dictionary for both tests
        clock.Restart();
        test1(items);
        clock.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time for naive unsorted: " + clock.ElapsedTicks.ToString());

        test2(items); //jit hit
        clock.Restart();
        test2(items);
        clock.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time for separated/branch prediction friendly: " + clock.ElapsedTicks.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void test1(IEnumerable<int> items)
    {
        foreach(int item in items)
        {
            //different code branches that still do significant work in the cpu
            // doing more work here results in a larger branch-prediction win, to a point
            if (item % 3 == 0)
            {   //force hash computation and multiplication op (both cpu-bound)
                ints[item] = (item * 2).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                doubles[(double)item] = (item * 3).ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    static void test2(IEnumerable<int> items)
    {
        //doing MORE work: need to evaluate our items two ways, allocate arrays
        var intItems = items.Where(i => i % 3 == 0).ToArray();
        var doubleItems = items.Where(i => i % 3 != 0).ToArray();

        // but now there is no branching... adding all the ints, then adding all the doubles.
        foreach (var item in intItems) { ints[item] = (item * 2).ToString(); }
        foreach (var item in doubleItems) { doubles[(double)item] = (item * 3).ToString(); }
    }
}
```

And the results on my machine is that the 2nd test, that does more work, ran faster:

> Time for naive unsorted: 1118652
>   Time for separated/branch prediction friendly: 1005190

The important thing to take away here is *not* that you need to go back and look at whether all your loops can benefit from branch prediction. This is just one of any number of CPU features that can make performance results surprise you. The important thing to take away here is that to know for sure how code will perform, you actually need to measure your performance. If you don't build this carefully the naive technique can still win (my first attempt didn't get the speed up I expected).

Additionally, I need to point out that there's not all that much difference in these cases. Was this performance gain worth it, or would you have done better to spend your time elsewhere? The only way to know that is actually measure the performance of your app as a whole, and find out where it's really spending it's time. Where is it really slower than it should be? This is called **profiling**, and there are tools out there to help you do this accurately.

Comment: Another one of those answers that I wish I'd written as a blog post first.

Comment: If all your blog posts are this good, I need to start reading your blog.

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
void Main()
{
        int x = GetInt();
        x = x < 5 ?  5 : x;
}

int GetInt()
{return 5;}
```

is translated in IL in this way

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery.GetInt
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0009:  blt.s       IL_000E
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_000C:  br.s        IL_000F
IL_000E:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_000F:  stloc.0     // x

GetInt:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0001:  ret
```

while this one

```
void Main()
{
    int x = GetInt();
    if (x < 5) x = 5;
}            

int GetInt()
{return 5;}
```

is translated to

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        UserQuery.GetInt
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0009:  bge.s       IL_000D
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_000C:  stloc.0     // x

GetInt:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0001:  ret
```

So this seems more 'efficient' (?).

But this is really a micro optimization that will never make any difference to your code, so, I suggest to go with the most readable one (and in my opinion this coincides with the last one)

**EDIT** 
Definitively the answer of Joel Coehoorn is the best one: (At least in terms of readability and code size)

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  call        UserQuery.GetInt
IL_0007:  call        System.Math.Max

GetInt:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0001:  ret
```

Comment: Why do you believe that the form of the IL has any bearing on the runtime efficiency? The IL doesn't run. The code you want to be looking at is the code that the jitter generates, not the code that the C# compiler generates. It's the jitter code that actually runs.

Comment: Yes, I haven't explained it in the answer and you are right of course. Mine was just a check to see if, at this level, there was some clearly advantage between the two ways to code. And, sure there is no great difference between the first two methods. However the idea from Mr Coehoorn  seems to be better here, or do you think that it will be optimized by the Runtime? Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: If you're going to measure the efficiency using code size like this, then the most efficient method is one that just calls another method to do its work. Put another way: how do you think `Math.Max()` is implemented.

Comment: @svick, I have really made no claims on efficiency of this code. I have just suggested to go with the best in terms of readability and code size.